# Camera Calibration OpenCV Camera as the input

Tags: c++, opencv, camera, real-time, camera-calibration

I use the code in the code from this tutorial to do a camera calibration on my laptop.

here's the link
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/calib3d/camera_calibration/camera_calibration.html#source-code

It run though but gave warnings:

```
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Users\jay\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe', Symbols loaded.
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\opencv\build\x86\vc11\bin\opencv_core248.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp110.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcr110.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\opencv\build\x86\vc11\bin\opencv_highgui248.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\lpk.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\usp10.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ole32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\oleaut32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.7601.18201_none_ec80f00e8593ece5\comctl32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvfw32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winmm.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shell32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\avifil32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msacm32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\avicap32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\version.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcr100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\imm32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msctf.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cryptbase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\uxtheme.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\clbcatq.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\devenum.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\setupapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cfgmgr32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\devobj.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntmarta.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\Wldap32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\wintrust.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\crypt32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msasn1.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msdmo.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\qcap.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\quartz.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dwmapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ksproxy.ax', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ksuser.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\d3d9.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\d3d8thk.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\vidcap.ax', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\Kswdmcap.ax', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\mfc42.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\odbc32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\odbcint.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\qedit.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\comdlg32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.7601.18120_none_72d2e82386681b36\GdiPlus.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ddraw.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dciman32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\igdumd32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\igddxva32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
Dll Loaded :-) 
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\igdvidproc32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\igdaux32.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\d3dim700.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\igddxva32.dll'
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\igdvidproc32.dll'
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\igdaux32.dll'
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\igdumd32.dll'
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\igdumd32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\igddxva32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
Dll Loaded :-) 
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\igdvidproc32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\igdaux32.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\igddxva32.dll'
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\igdvidproc32.dll'
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\igdaux32.dll'
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\igdumd32.dll'
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msyuv.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x17bc) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msyuv.dll'
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0xd4) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1594) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1390) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[5996] ConsoleApplication1.exe: Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

My problem is how can to input my images in real time using the camera of my laptop or do i have to record a video or take snapshots of the checkered board and put it in an xml file?

Answer (score 0):

From what I've seen, you use `imread()` to load an already-saved image from your hard drive. In other words, take snapshots and work with them.

Comment: what if i want to use the camera as the input? how will i do it?

Comment: @user3388464 Take a look at this link. It shows how to capture video from a device. http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-open